# java, spring boot Autogenerate getters and setters at runtime

Tags: java, setter, getter, autocreate

I have a set of bean classes. I would like to know the best approach to generate the getters and setters automatically at run time. Can anyone help please.

Comment: Use your IDE's "generate code" function?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit, what do you mean at run time. is it that when you run your java program you want some other java classes to be automatically filled with its getter and setters. Also try posting some code of what do you have and what you want

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a way to generate the getters/setters at runtime, but [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) has annotations that you can add that will generate the getters/setters for you at compile time. It is a pretty seamless experience. Lombok can also generate builder classes, toString, equals/hashCode methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lombok which generates getter, setter, toString methods at runtime. It is a powerful and very helpful library. I provide below the link.

https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try Lambok and post if successful in doing it.

Answer (score -1):

After you have created the variables in the class, right click, select Source, select Generate Getters and Setters.

Comment: Did you miss to check the question ? It says at runtime.